# org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist

Tags: hadoop, nutch

I have set up Apache Nutch with single node of Hadoop. When I execute the crawl command it starts the crawling. However there is an exception throwing after few minutes.

cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does
not exist: (please refer to the image 1)

**This is the invalid path according to the exception**
hdfs://localhost:54310/user/duleendra/TestCrawl/segments/drwxrwxrwx/crawl_generate

Actually there is no such path in hdfs.

How does this drwxrwxrwx come ?

**In hdfs I can see the following path**

hdfs://localhost:54310/user/duleendra/TestCrawl/segments/20150506222506/crawl_generate

(please refer to the image 2 as well).

[image]

[image]

Have I missed anything?

Thanks

Duleendra

Comment: drwxrwxrwx is actually the permission of folder

Comment: Yes but no idea how this path comes with drwxrwxrwx hdfs://localhost:54310/user/duleendra/TestCrawl/segments/drwxrwxrwx/crawl_generate

Comment: Seems like calling `ls -al` in shell script but expected `ls` output and interpret the result

Comment: You mean crawl.sh script ?

Comment: I don't know, it's the script that generate the path :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a bug in Unix based systems like OSX and FreeBsd . Nutch's crawl will not work in them. Try ubuntu.